# WinDbg Hanging *BUSY* Debuggee is running

Tags: windows-7, sdk, windbg

I am trying to run an .exe through WinDbg 6.12 on Win7 32, It starts and goes through modload then stops and displays the Message

*BUSY* Debuggee is running...

I have unchecked "Resolve Unqualified Symbols" from the debug menu and nothing. No exceptions are showing and everything else appears to be correct...

Any Ideas?

RickUm

Answer (score 2):

That's the normal message displayed while the debuggee process is executing.